# Please help me choose which is the fixed and which is the random effect in a linear mixed effects model

Tags: linear, fixed-effects-model

- Hi. I am a beginner in statistics so please bear with me. I have a dataset where I randomized participants into 2 conditions (Agency and Non-agency) then had them report their ethical responses on a scale of 1-5 (the DV) after reading 3 different vignettes. I want to check for differences between the conditions and also differences between vignettes for each condition.  My original plan was to use a two-way mixed ANOVA since each participant reports on 3 vignettes (within) and the condition is between-group. However the DV is non-normally distributed so I can’t use a parametric test. So I opted for a linear mixed effects model analysis.
- The problem is I can’t figure out which of my factors should be fixed and which should be random effects - I just can’t seem to wrap my head around the difference between the two. Do you have any insight into the two?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you ran into a misunderstanding. Linear mixed-effects models also have to satisfy the assumption of the normality of the residuals. However, as you may notice, this assuption, common to all statistical models derived from the general linear model, like ANOVAs, t-tests, linear regression and linear mixed-effects models, refers to the residuals and not to the dependent variable, which is a common misconception. Therefore, the conformity of the model with normality is checked after the model is fitted to the data. If you have a lot of data, the central limit theorem allows you to ignore some deviations from normality.
The difference between a mixed ANOVA and a linear mixed-effects model is that the former does not have to obey the assumption of sphericity. However, it has to obey all other linear model assumptions (normality of residuals, homoscedasticity, linearity, non-multicollinearity, independence, etc) plus the normality of the random effects.

In your case, the ethical response is the dependent variable (R), the participant is the subject (S), the condition is a fixed between-subjects effect (B) and the vignette is a fixed within-subjects effect (W).

R ~ B + W

Random effects are allowed to vary randomly between each subject. If you want to put some random effects, you have to choose what you want to allow to vary between subjects. If you only want to allow the baseline to vary, then you will add a random intercept by subject effect.

R ~ B + W + (1 | S)

If you also want to allow the within-subjects effect to vary, then you will add a random slope by subject effect (along with the random intercept)

R ~ B + W + (1 | S) + (0 + W | S)

The above can be directly used in R with the lmer() function in the lme4 package. You do not have to declare explicitly which is the between and the within variable in the syntax.

Lastly, if the above seem overwhelming and, as you stated, you are a beginner in statistics, I would suggest that you devote some time to grasp the basics of the general linear model and linear regression first until you feel confident with them. Thereafter, you will be free to extend to linear mixed-effects models. Take it at your own pace and do not be intimidated. It pays off.